# How can i show an image fullscreen from a little preview?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, fullscreen

I want to show an image fullscreen each time users tap on a little preview of the image itself.

I was thinking of creating a UIButton with the image and then call in the image fullscreen from a function.

If there's a faster way, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by faster way?

Comment: I don't know, something that already implements what i wanna do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a view controller that takes an image in its initialiser and just shows the image with a "Done" button. Then have your thumbnails displayed on buttons which when tapped initialise this new view controller and present it modally. Obviously you'd also need to wire up the "Done" button to dismiss it.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i was thinking of! The problem is that i already have a "ScreenViewController" with the image inside: it's called when the user taps on a "screenshot" button in another view and it has a little toolbar with a button that goes back to the previous vC. The image in the ScreenViewController is not fullscreen. Do i need to create another viewController or?

Comment: You could present it as a model view controller to make it fullscreen. i.e. [self presentModalViewController:fullScreenVC animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

How about just resizing a button on press action.. You initialize the button saving both frames (thumb and fullscreen), set both normal and highlighted images to thumb image and store the BOOL state for fullscreen/normal states. Now in the press action you can use UIView animate methods to animate the button frame resizing.. If the state is normal, you should first set both images to fullscreen images and then animate, if it is in fullscreen you should first animate frame to normal state and then change images to thumb images.

Comment: Yeah it may be it, but it's a bit hard for me - i'm a newcomer in iOS dev world. But i'll try it anyway! Thank you.